Metaboss error, account
Error: Action failed with error: failed to get account data
I use solana CLI and metaboss on Windows
I try to update metadata for my token. How to deal with it ?
Address are correct, try account and token address just in case.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
